# Localization .strings troubleshooting

Tags: swift, string, xcode, build, localization

My SwiftUI app is localized with .strings files.

Now I am testing the localization with only one .strings file (for the English language).

The occurrences in this file are in the form of "key"="value";

I checked the content and " ; chars are ok, escaped unicode (\uxxxx) and \n " ' chars are ok, all entries are on one single line.

the file is in a folder named en.lproj which is inside the Resources folder.

In the build phases tab of the project the en.lproj folder is listed.

Here's the function that translates the occurrences:

```
func getLocalizedString(_ keyParam:String)->String
{

    let result=NSLocalizedString(keyParam,comment: "")

    return result
}
```

All files seem to be in the project, no need to add them again.

When running the app on the simulator (language=English) the keys are displayed and not the traslated values, like

title_label instead of Title

so I think the translating function does not load the .strings file.

I know this is a issue for everyone trying to localize their app, so I am asking here which checks can I perform to troubleshoot and fix the localization?

Comment: Is the strings file localized?

Comment: @lorem ipsum The file is created to implement the localization. What do you mean? Just the keys are not English, so English is the values, it is one of the localizations. Maybe the method thinks that the keys are English? How to make this kind of localization work?

Comment: @Kishan Bhatiya I need to debug inside the NSLocalizedString but "step into" is about the thread not the method call, if I understand correctly how XCode debug works. I am from Java world, and there I just would step into the instruction. How to do that with XCode?

Comment: Strings file > File Inspector > Localization > Localize . The line within the file will look something like `"key" = "value";` the key being the same for all language files and `keyParam`

Comment: @lorem ipsum I just get the "Identity and type" panel, no Localization>Localize

Comment: Below "Identify and Type" do you have "Localization" and check boxes for languages? if so, it is localized already if not, I don't know how to fix it without more info. Did you create the file using "New File" and clicking on the strings file type?

Comment: @lorem ipsum There are no check boxes. The type is "default: localizable strings" Maybe it has to be "localizable dictionary"? I created the file months ago, I think I just created the file as txt, with .strings extension.

Comment: That is likely your issue then. Just create a new file Right Click on Folder > New File > Strings File then localize it. Paste all your keys and values in the new file

Comment: @lorem ipsum Will I do create the file in the en.lproj folder? There I have also other localized resources that seem to be correctly loaded with Build.main.url. So I keep that.

Comment: This file will have its own language files. Just put it in any folder for now maybe under your "Shared" folder?. I don't know what architecture pattern you are using so advise on a location. You can always move it later.

Comment: @lorem ipsum Are the strings inside the new "general" file like "key"="key"; ? Am I right?

Comment: "title_label" = "Title";